# docker-compose build with new tag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose which looks like:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  jobsaf-server:
    build: 
      context: ./application
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    container_name: jobsaf-server
    env_file: 
      - ./application/.env
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "mongo"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./application/server:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/server
      - ./application/public/assets:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/public/assets
      - ./application/uploads:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/uploads
      - ./application/sitemaps:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/sitemaps
      - ./application/rss:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/rss
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    tty: true
    env_file: 
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=${APP_HOST}
      - NGINX_PORT=${APP_PORT}
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - TZ=Asia/Kabul
    links:
      - jobsaf-server
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl/star_jobs_af.pem:/etc/ssl/star_jobs_af.pem
      - ./nginx/ssl/jobs.af.key:/etc/ssl/jobs.af.key
      - ./nginx/ssl/star_jobs_af.crt:/etc/ssl/star_jobs_af.crt
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/data/db"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:27017:27017"
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    tty: true
volumes:
  db-data:
    # - /data/db
networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

It build `jobsaf-server:latest` by default.

what I want is to keep the old tag and build the new one.

let say, while building the images I should pass something similar to this

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.production --tag=1.0.1`

the above command should build for me and image with tag `jobsaf-server:1.0.1`

Is it really possible to have such result?
Or is there any alternative solution for it

Thanks in advance.

Note: I want to keep the old image, in case if my new image has issue, then I can use the old image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  jobsaf-server:
    image: jobsaf-server:${TAG}
    build: 
      context: ./application
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
...
```

The best way to supply the tag is with a .env file like this:

```
TAG=1.0.1
```

Docker-compose will pick this up automatically.

Comment: Is it passible via terminal? for example, `docker-compose build --TAG=1.0.1`

Comment: Yes, use --build-arg TAG=1.0.1. if this doesn't work then you can set the environment variable before running docker-compose build

Comment: Thanks, can I use `docker-compose up -d --build-arg TAG=1.0.1`

Comment: I double checked and that is only for build arguments in the Dockerfile. You need to export the TAG env variable first. How exactly to do it depends on your operating system. On Mac should be like: TAG=1.0.1 docker-compose up -d --build

Answer (score 1):

From **@Mihai** suggestion following steps worked for me, incase if someone else needed.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  jobsaf-server:
    image: jobsaf-server:${TAG}
    build: 
      context: ./application
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
```

**To build**:

Run `TAG=1.0 docker-compose build` it will create `jobsaf-server:1.0`

**To Up**:

Run `TAG=1.0 docker-compose up -d`

**To down**:

Run `TAG=1.0 docker-compose down`

Note: we can add `TAG` to `.env` file also by default.